# Odoo 13 : create multiple records via create function

Tags: python, date, odoo, record, odoo-13

This is my first create function I have ever written in Odoo13. I want to get a period between 2 dates **begin_date** and **end_date** and the dates should be saved in a list. From this list I want to create records for a single employee for every day in the list. But my code doesn't seem to be correct and I get this kind of error :  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

This is my code :

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date
from calendar import monthrange


from odoo import api, fields, models, tools
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, AccessError, ValidationError
from odoo.tools import date_utils


class TimeOff(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.timeoff'
    _rec_name = 'employ_id'

    employ_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Employee', required='1')

    date = fields.Date('Date', required=True, index=True,
                       default=fields.Date.context_today)

    begin_date = fields.Datetime(
        'First Day of Leave', required='1')

    day_hours = fields.Integer('Off hours per day', default='8', required='1')
    end_date = fields.Datetime(
        'Last Day of Leave')

###### create function #######
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        range_date = []    # empty list
        if self.employ_id: # check if field has value
            if self.begin_date and self.end_date: # check if field has value
                range_date = self.calc_dates(
                    self.begin_date, self.end_date, mode='date') # call custom function and expect a list to be returned
                if range_date is None:
                    raise ValidationError("Something went wrong") # list is empty
                else: # iterate through list and create record for each date 
                    for day in range_date:
                        vals = {
                            'employ_id': self.employ_id,
                            'begin_date': day}
                        return super(TimeOff, self).create(vals)

### custom function to get all dates between begin_date and end_date #####

    def calc_dates(self, date1, date2, mode='date'):
        date_from = fields.Date.from_string(date1)
        date_to = fields.Date.from_string(date2)

        delta = date_to - date_from

        if delta.days < 0: 
            return None

        dates = []

        for n in range(delta.days + 1):
            if mode == 'date':  # returns dates as date format
                dates.append(date_from + timedelta(days=n))
            if mode == 'string': # returns dates as string format
                dates.append(fields.Date.to_string(
                    date_from + timedelta(days=n)))
        return dates
```

So when I press create I get this error :

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1327, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1319, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 385, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model_create(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 366, in _call_kw_model_create
    return result.id if isinstance(args[0], Mapping) else result.ids
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Either I can't use **self** iin this issue or something is wrong with the return

Answer (score 1):

Since `self` is an empty record set, `self.employ_id` will be evaluated to `False` and Odoo will not execute the if statement, then will return the default value `None`.

You can call `super` (without returning the result) with a list of vals, but this will change the behavior of the create method, it is supposed to [return the created record](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/fr/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.create) from `vals`.

You could use a wizard to create `project.timeoff` records.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem is that the values for the record will be imported through a csv file later. And in that csv file there is only a period from begin to end. I have to display this in a grid view since every cell in the grid view (enterprise) is matched to one record I have to automatically create the  records. Like Mitchel Admin has from 01.10 to 06.10, so gap should be filled with dates and for every date there should be one record for the same person in the end. Is it possible to do with a wizard?

Comment: Do you need to reuse the wizard to import later a similar CSV file? I think it is preferable that you transform the CSV file before importing it.

Comment: Yes it should be able to update the data with the same csv file but without dto double the records. I cant transform the CSV manually  unfortunaltely, because the file gets genereated automatically from else where and my co-workers have no experience with csv files.

Comment: What I will do now is to not modify the create function. Instead I will put my code in a custom method and create a button to call the method

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has the same issue and wants to create records automatically here is my solution :

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date
from calendar import monthrange


from odoo import api, fields, models, tools
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, AccessError, ValidationError
from odoo.tools import date_utils


class TimeOff(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.timeoff'
    _rec_name = 'employ_id'

    employ_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Employee', required='1')

    date = fields.Date('Date', required=True, index=True,
                       default=fields.Date.context_today)

    begin_date = fields.Datetime(
        'First Day of Leave', required='1')

    day_hours = fields.Integer('Off hours per day', default='8', required='1')
    end_date = fields.Datetime(
        'Last Day of Leave')
############################################ create um zw periode von datum, records zu erstellen ##############################################

    def update_record(self):
        range_date = []
        for rec in self:
            if rec.employ_id:
                if rec.begin_date and rec.end_date:
                    range_date = rec.calc_dates(
                        rec.begin_date, rec.end_date)
                    if range_date is None:
                        raise ValidationError("Something went wrong")
                    else:
                        for day in range_date:
                            val = {
                                'employ_id': rec.employ_id.id,
                                'begin_date': day}
                            self.create(val)
                            self._cr.commit()


################################################### funktion um periode mit datum zw begin und end_date auzugeben (als liste) ########################################################################


    def calc_dates(self, date1, date2):
        date_from = date1
        date_to = date2

        delta = date_to - date_from

        if delta.days < 0:
            return None

        dates = []

        for n in range(delta.days + 1):
            dates.append(date_from + timedelta(days=n))

        return dates
```

Dont forget to create a custom button and call the function :

```
  <record id="project_timeoff_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">view.project.timeoff.tree</field>
          <field name="model">project.timeoff</field>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="TimeOff">
              <field name="employ_id" string="Employee"/>
              <field name="begin_date"/>
              <field name="end_date"/> 
              <field name="day_hours"/>
              <!-- <field name="requested_hours"/> -->
              <button name="update_record" string="Update" class="btn-primary" type="object" />
            </tree>
          </field>
  </record>
```

**PS: The button will be show after each record in the tree view, I havent found a solution to put it in the header**

[image: Tree View]